# Process in background

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application and I need a specific process to run in background (all the time) and update the DB from time to time. What's the best way to do it? Create a controller with a method and run it in a thread in background? Any other option?

Comment: Just keep it separated from MVC (and IIS)

Comment: If your solution includes SQL Server you can use SQL Agent for that. Your MVC app will be independent.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to create a separate application which you can run as a Windows Service or, if it's only a periodic update, a Scheduled Task.

The benefit of using a Scheduled Task is that you don't have to write the scheduler code - it's all handled for you by the operating system. Your application just consists of the code needed to update the database.

By divorcing it completely from your web application, it makes it more secure and easier to maintain (you can update either the web application or service independently of each other).

Comment: Do I need a special computer \ OS for windows service?

Comment: @tamarg - no. Windows services can run on any Windows OS. Though a Scheduled task might be the better option - depending on how the database update is triggered.